# Prevent IE8's agreesive caching

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-8

I am having an issue with IE8 and its caching behaviour.

If I hit the page index.html and then continue to hit it again I am servered a page from the server.

However if I hit the page index.html?ui=v2 then index.html then index.html?ui=v2 I am served the page from cache.

The problem is the querystring ui=v2 is used to set a cookie which dtermines the view to deliver. As the page comes from cache the cookies view mode is not updated and I am served the same content as displayed for index.html (with no querystring).

This is IE8 and below, no other browsers.

Keen for any input Ideally I do not want to update the meta or response headers.

Thanks in advancecokkies